# Adobe reader on wine not rendering text entry boxes

Tags: wine, winetricks, adobe-reader, adobe-acrobat

I have just installed adobe acrobat reader latest version using wine and I noticed that there are no text entry fields anywhere. Originally, the text labels were not visible as well but I managed to make them work by installing windows 7 fonts as proposed on another thread. Now I'm stuck with [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFkMb.png) blank text boxes everywhere which restricts me from opening password-protected documents as it doesn't show the text entry field box.

OS - Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop (GNOME variant)

Wine - 5.8-1

Comment: There is a lot of Linux software that can view pdf. Why insall that on wine?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I'm getting this problem, too. Kubuntu 20.04.3, Adobe Reader DC 2020.013.20064 (though snap says 2021.007.20091 Rev 62?!), wine 6.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this still a problem, but I got it to work with new Acrobat Reader (2021). Here are the steps I used:

- Install [Segoe-UI ttf fonts](https://github.com/mrbvrz/segoe-ui-linux)

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrbvrz/segoe-ui-linux/master/install.sh
chmod +x install.sh
./install.sh
```

- Install `mpg123:i386`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mpg123:i386
```

- Install additional dependencies:

```
sudo apt install mpg123 whiptail wget cabextract p7zip p7zip-full unrar unzip wget zenity git
```

- Configure fonts using winetricks:

```
$ WINEPREIX=/path/to/acrobatreader/prefix winetricks atmlib riched20 wsh57 mspatcha vcrun2013 allfonts
```

Comment: thanks Nmath, steps look better !